# Can't index a numeric vector from data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have done this several times, but it has been a while since I use R and apparently I am missing something.

I have a long format data.frame called `Mean_A_trial_long` of the following form:

```
> head(Mean_A_trial_long,30)
   Trial TrialType  Block variable     value
1    101    Opaque Block2       RT  961.6000
2    102    Opaque Block2       RT  713.5000
3    103    Opaque Block2       RT  714.4444
4    104    Opaque Block2       RT  757.8750
5    105    Opaque Block2       RT  992.8000
6    106    Opaque Block2       RT 1114.7000
7    107    Opaque Block2       RT  770.6250
8    108    Opaque Block2       RT  835.5714
9    109    Opaque Block2       RT  693.6667
10   110    Opaque Block2       RT  816.5714
11   111    Opaque Block2       RT  748.2000
12   112    Opaque Block2       RT  789.3333
13   113    Opaque Block2       RT  848.8000
14   114    Opaque Block2       RT  883.3077
15   115    Opaque Block2       RT  933.8333
16   116    Opaque Block2       RT  879.2000
17   117    Opaque Block2       RT  802.5000
18   118    Opaque Block2       RT  899.8750
19   119    Opaque Block2       RT  821.2000
20   120    Opaque Block2       RT  820.1250
21   121    Opaque Block2       RT  755.6250
22   122    Opaque Block2       RT  900.1667
23   123    Opaque Block2       RT  840.5556
24   124    Opaque Block2       RT  755.4000
25   125    Opaque Block2       RT  657.4000
26   126    Opaque Block2       RT 1112.1429
27   127    Opaque Block2       RT  972.6667
28   128    Opaque Block2       RT  765.1667
29   129    Opaque Block2       RT  959.0000
30   130    Opaque Block2       RT  844.1429
```

Crucially, `TrialType` is a factor with two levels: `Opaque` and `Transparent`. For each of these two levels there are two instances of the same number in the column `trial`. So the column `trial` goes from 101 to 200 having `Opaque` in `TrialType` and then goes again from 101 to 200 having `Transparent` in `TrialType`. It does this until trial 500.

What I want to do is to extract two vectors with 10 trials each, one corresponding to the first 10 trials of the `Opaque` condition and one to the first 10 trials of the `Transparent` condition.

This is what I was trying:

```
First10Transparent <- Mean_A_trial_long$value[Mean_A_trial_long$TrialType == "Transparent" & (Mean_A_trial_long$Trial > 100 & Mean_A_trial_long$trial < 111)]
```

But this gives me an empty object called First10Transparent with nothing on it...

Any clues as to what I am missing/doing wrong are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try this `by(Mean_A_trial_long, Mean_A_trial_long$TrialType, function(x) head(x["value"],5))`

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is embarrassing... And also goes to show you the importance of detail.

What was wrong was that when indexing the `Trial` column, I wrote the first time with capital T (corect) but the second with lower-case t (wrong). This is why I was getting an empty object.

Correcting Trial to capital T on both lines gave me the desired outoput:

```
First10Transparent <- Mean_A_trial_long$value[Mean_A_trial_long$TrialType == "Transparent" &     (Mean_A_trial_long$Trial > 100 & Mean_A_trial_long$Trial < 111)]
> First10Transparent
[1]  887.8889  797.1000  742.8000  660.1667  892.5556 1165.5000  644.8333  650.5714  681.1250  756.8571
```

Comment: As a side note: I suggest using either `?with(...)` or `?subset()` -- though only for interactive use -- in order to avoid typing `Mean_A_trial_long$` a hundred times which makes it harder to read your code.

Answer (score 1):

**Using with()**

```
Mean_A_trial_long$value[with(Mean_A_trial_long,TrialType == "Opaque" & Trial > 100 & Trial < 111)]
Mean_A_trial_long$value[with(Mean_A_trial_long,TrialType == "Transparent" & Trial > 200 & Trial < 211)]
```

I've modified your code to include a `with()` statement. `With` has several advantages because:

- it only requires you to type the name of the data once
- reduces potential for coding errors
- simplifies your code

**Using your code**

You can also use your original code to create this statement:

```
Mean_A_trial_long$value[Mean_A_trial_long$TrialType == "Transparent" & (Mean_A_trial_long$Trial > 100 & Mean_A_trial_long$trial < 111)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the subset you want.

```
 First10Transparent <- Mean_A_trial_long[as.character(Mean_A_trial_long$TrialType) == "Transparent" & (Mean_A_trial_long$Trial > 100 & Mean_A_trial_long$trial < 111),]
```